# When I add dependencies of sanity.io in React.js project I faced these problems

Tags: reactjs, sanity

```
PS C:\Users\KC\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce> npm create sanity@latest
Need to install the following packages:
  create-sanity@3.12.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y
You're setting up a new project!
We'll make sure you have an account with Sanity.io. Then we'll
install an open-source JS content editor that connects to
the real-time hosted API on Sanity.io. Hang on.

Press ctrl + C at any time to quit.

Prefer web interfaces to terminals?
You can also set up best practice Sanity projects with
your favorite frontends on https://www.sanity.io/templates

Looks like you already have a Sanity-account. Sweet!

✔ Fetching existing projects
? Select project to use Create new project
? Your project name: sanity_ecommerce
Your content will be stored in a dataset that can be public or private, depending on
whether you want to query your content with or without authentication.
The default dataset configuration has a public dataset named "production".
? Use the default dataset configuration? Yes
✔ Creating dataset
? Would you like to add configuration files for a Sanity project in this Next.js folder? No
? Project output path: C:\Users\KC\Desktop\ecommerce\ecommerce\sanityecommerce
? Select project template Clean project with no predefined schemas
? Do you want to use TypeScript? No
✔ Bootstrapping files from template
✔ Resolving latest module versions
✔ Creating default project files
? Package manager to use for installing dependencies? npm
Running 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps'

Error: Command failed with exit code 2 (ENOENT): npm install --legacy-peer-deps
spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
```

I am creating ecommerce application using react.js, next.js, Sanity and Stripe.

Comment: It looks like you are on Windows. Do you have `npm` installed already?

Comment: I think Sanity does not support Windows. It probably tries to run a command that does not work on Windows. Other people also have [issues with Windows](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/2591). A possible solution is using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).